# Can I make a MySQL view that adds a random amount within a range to any decimal fields in the table?

Tags: mysql

I built a dashboard for a company to number crunch data from their Quickbooks and they want to demo it, but without people seeing their sensitive financial data.

I think that the easiest way for me to do this would be to create a new database which is views of the main database, but semi-randomly changing the figures, keeping the ratios similar but the amounts different. I would imagine the range would be something like add between 300% and 340% to every invoice line item, for example.

I do have other ways of achieving this, but I feel this would be the simplest in terms of maintenance, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a Data Masking technique

See the Number and Data Variance section on the [Data Masking Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_masking).

The basic strategy is obfuscate by +- some percentage.

Without knowing anything about your data, here's a general example with a 10% variance (RAND() returns a random value between 0 and 1).

```
CREATE VIEW DATA_MASK
AS 
SELECT (DATA + (DATA * ((RAND() - .5) / 5)) as newDATA
FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: That looks like what I want, I am wondering if I can do it in such a way that it works like a MySQL view and I always have a database with recently dated, but masked numbers.

Comment: I added a code snippet that should get you started.  Maybe that helps?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I changed the formula so it adds a percentage rather than an absolute, then created one view per table in a new database and now I can just switch database for a (readonly) demo version with randomised numbers.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Maybe you wouldn't mind accepting the answer and adding an up-vote then too...?

Comment: Done, strange I thought I did that when I responded to the comment. You may also want to reword your answer as (unless I misunderstand it) it is not a 10% variance on the data, it's just adding a random number in the range -10 to 10

Comment: You are exactly right!  Thanks for the correction.  I just edited the answer to reflect a 10% variance as requested.